# Not being able to reference a variable from outside the loop

Tags: javascript, loops, return

Iam not able to reference a variable from outside the loop in the following function. I want to use the value inside the function itself but the scope doesnt seem to allow it.

```
function coinOnTheTable(m, k, board) {
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === "*") {
        const a = `${i}${j}`;
        return a;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Works, While

```
function coinOnTheTable(m, k, board) {
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === "*") {
        const a = `${i}${j}`;
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

gives an error

```
return a;
     ^
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because a variable defined as `const` or `let` has "block scope". That means it is only visible inside the nearest set of curly braces. So:

```
function foo() {
   const foo = 'foo-string';
   if(1) {
     const bar = 'bar-string';
     console.log(bar); // This is fine
   }
   console.log(foo); // This is also fine
   console.log(bar); // Error!
}
```

To solve your problem, you need to define your variable outside of the block defined by the nested for loop. So:

```
function coinOnTheTable(m, k, board) {
    let a;
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < m; j++){
            if(board[i][j] === "*"){
                a = `${i}${j}`;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Note, the reason it changes from `const` to `let` is because `const` variables cannot be reassigned, but since you want to declare it as `undefined` (at the start of the function, then assign a string to it (inside the loop), you need to be able to reassign it.

Answer (score 0):

make `a` function scope:

```
function coinOnTheTable(m, k, board) {
    let a;
    for(var i=0;i<board.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<m;j++){
            if(board[i][j]==="*"){
                const a=`${i}${j}`;
            }
        }
    }
     return a;
}
```